# SQL insert with MS Access fails

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have just started to do some coding with Access and trying to create a function that adds a row to a table but this would not work.

I have created a simple table (Table1) with two columns "FirstName" and "LastName" and a button that fires off the following code:

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()
    AppendRow "Table1", "John", "Doe"
End Sub
```

Where AppendRow is:

```
Function AppendRow(toTableName As String, firstName As String, lastName As String) As Boolean
   ' Returns True on success, false otherwise
   ' USAGE: AppendRow "toTableName", "firstName", "lastName"

   On Error GoTo errhandler
   Dim strSql As String

   'Create the SQL string
   strSql = "INSERT INTO " & toTableName & " (FirstName, LastName) " & _
        "VALUES ('" & firstName & "', '" & lastName & "');"


   'Print the SQL so we can paste into the query build if there are errors
   Debug.Print strSql
   MsgBox strSql

   'Run the SQL Query
   CurrentDb.Execute strSql

   'If no errors return true
   AppendRow = True

ExitHere:
   Exit Function

errhandler:
   'There is an error return false
   AppendRow = False
   With Err
      MsgBox "Error " & .Number & vbCrLf & .Description, vbOKOnly Or vbCritical, "AppendTable"
   End With
   Resume ExitHere
End Function
```

The SQL string looks like this

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (FirstName, LastName) VALUES ('John', 'Doe')
```

**EDIT**: Added missing quotes.

Comment: Did you try to add quotes: INSERT INTO Table1 (FirstName, LastName) VALUES ('John', 'Doe')?

Comment: Great! That removed the error, however no rows are added to the table.

Comment: may be your variables are empty, try debug the code to know what do they have assigned. sorry for bad language

Comment: make sure you can add new rows manually to your table, there may be something going on there you didn't expect

Comment: removed the [tag:sql] tag for two reasons: 1) so it formats "properly"; 2) because this issue isn't with SQL, the only SQL being provided is 100% correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You reported that you are now quoting the text values you attempt to insert, but that you do not get the row inserted and apparently no error message.  I don't understand why that is so, and offer this simple procedure simply to see whether you can get something to work.

```
Public Sub AppendRow(ByVal toTableName As String, _
        ByVal pFirstName As String, _
        ByVal pLastName As String)
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    '* ensure SetWarnings is not off *'
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(toTableName, dbOpenTable, dbAppendOnly)
    With rs
        .AddNew
        !firstName = pFirstName
        !lastName = pLastName
        .Update
        .Close
    End With
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```

I didn't include error handling because this is intended only for testing.  I made it a subroutine instead of a function because I noticed you weren't using the function's return value in your code which called the function.

If this doesn't work for you, please tell us the error message you receive and which line in that procedure triggers the error.

Comment: Tested with this code too but I got no additional rows in my table, it just fails silently. I can add rows manually however. Do I have to do something special with my table to add rows by code?

Comment: I don't understand how the insert attempt can fail without an error, unless `SetWarnings` has been turned off.  Please try the revised code sample and tell us what happens.

Comment: No change :( Entering the SQL string manually into a query window gives me this error though: ".. didn't add 1 record to the table due to key violations." Any clues?

Comment: Found the problem: You have to refresh the table to see the changes... :/ I have a few hundreds of John Doe's in it now :P

Comment: OK ... well if the rows were added successfully all along, that's a whole 'nother story!

Answer (score 1):

HansUp's code didnt work for me until I removed the dbAppendOnly option from the OpenRecordSet function call. MS Help documentation implies that it is only valid for Dynaset RecordSets, not TableSet Recordsets. Changed it to "Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(toTableName, dbOpenTable)" and it worked.

But his code was extremely helpful and I am very grateful. I had been going around and around unable to make my .Execute "INSERT "...-type code work either. I have no idea what was going on with that. It worked once and I made a minor change... Maybe my blood pressure peaking from my aggravation had something to do with it.

btw, @ymail.com is a valid email domain despite what your automated eddress checker says.